# How can I subscribe (e-mail or RSS) to updates on a certain organization's Facebook page?

Tags: rss, facebook

A favorite theater of mine releases new events using Facebook and Twitter only. How can I subscribe using e-mail or RSS to their Facebook page?

Comment: http://bloggingwithamy.com/subscribe-facebook-page-rss/ or just get a facebook account

Comment: Add it as an answer. @Sickest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From : http://bloggingwithamy.com/subscribe-facebook-page-rss

Step 1: Grab the Facebook page ID number

You may see the ID at the end of the page's URL, however, it's very likely the Facebook page you'd like to follow has a vanity URL. In this case you need to find the page ID. It's easy to do this.

Go to the page you want to follow. For example, my Facebook page's URL is:

```
http://www.facebook.com/BloggingWithAmy
```

Now, replace the "www" with "graph" like so:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/BloggingWithAmy
```

Click that URL and you'll see something like this:

[image]

bwa facebook page id

Copy the ID number on the first line (without quotes) and paste it into this URL (just replace mine here):

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=356075447067&format=rss20
```

Step 2: Subscribe in your reader

Copy the URL above and open your RSS reader. I use Google Reader (and it appears many of you do too).

[image]

subscribe to facebook page in reader

Here are the steps:

```
Click the red Subscribe button.
Paste the above URL into the box.
Click "Add."
```

That's it! Now you can catch all the updates for that page right in your reader. Easy peasy!